# Excel, to auto-populate a cell, based on three other cells' input

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to make a spreadsheet that will handle reservations for a studio hotel.
There are 3 parameters to consider: the reservation's month, day and the number of one of six studios - so, the staff enters these 3 parameters at the top of the page, and excel inserts "1" in the appropriate cell below (see image: sample). Result: studio booked on that day of that month.
In the attached image's example, the cell with the value of 1 should be F13.
I know this might be done with vlookup, or with index / match, but I have no idea how to structure it. Thank you in advance for any help!

[image: sample]

Comment: I suppose you need a solution that auto-populated values stays in their cells after the top three cells are modified. Unfortunately that's not possible, only at most one cell will be auto-populated at any time. The only way to populate cells permanently, is to use VBA. Please clarify what exactly you need.

Comment: Yes, VBA, I kind of thought so. I know some basic functions, but I usually hit "record" to do macros :-) How would you do that in VBA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

frame challenge... create of table of dates/studio number/value (`=1`), then just do a pivot table. Any new reservations would just be added to the table. Here's a screenshot, I think this should be enough to get you started:
[image]

Comment: Nice, I like it. I'll get to work right away!